# Tailwind grid-cols not working in production with Next

Tags: next.js, components, tailwind-css

I have a Next project, repo here:
https://github.com/DoctorSte/remoteOS

I have a Columns component that has a class called grid-cols-[x] where X is a prop.

```
export const Columns = ({
  children,
  columns,
  border,
  background,
  align,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <section
      className={`grid  md:grid-cols-${columns} grid-cols-1 items-${align} border-t-${border} ${background} gap-4 px-10 py-10 lg:px-48 w-full `}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </section>
  );
};
```

Locally it shows up ok but in production the column structure brakes.
On inspection, the section has 'grid-cols-4' as a class but appears as single column.
Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the custom color in tailwind not defined in NextJS production stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68029040/why-is-the-custom-color-in-tailwind-not-defined-in-nextjs-production-stage)

Comment: This is a really good answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71067473/6569716

Answer (score 7):

You can't [string concatenate](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html) the names or tailwind /postcss will not pick them up during the build process - the classes won't get added to the build.

```js
 className={`grid  ${columns === 4 ? 'md:grid-cols-4 sm:grid-cols-2': ''}`}
```

You'd have to evaluate how your dynamic classes are generated to see if there is a way to do it inline with the whole name (maybe just store the whole className).

Alternatively - you can add css that doesn't get purged by tailwind. See my [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68029040/why-is-the-custom-color-in-tailwind-not-defined-in-nextjs-production-stage/68029107#68029107) on a similar but  slightly different issue.

Comment: Wow that's a huge negative of tailwind I didn't know about.

Comment: This answer saved me hours of debugging, thanks!