# How to create a TailwindCSS grid with a dynamic amount of grid columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I'm using Vue3 with TailwindCSS and want to create a grid with a dynamic `grid-cols-{n}` class. I know that TailwindCSS supports up to 12 columns by default but I can't customize the theme because the amount of columns is completely dynamic.

Given the following plain HTML / Js example

```js
const amountOfItemsPerRow = 16;

const container = document.getElementById("container");

for (let i = 0; i < amountOfItemsPerRow; i++) {
  const item = document.createElement("div");
  item.innerText = i;
  container.appendChild(item);
}

container.classList.add(`grid-cols-${amountOfItemsPerRow}`); // this doesn't work if the value is greater than 12
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div id="container" class="grid"></div>
```

This code works fine if `amountOfItemsPerRow` is smaller or equal than 12, otherwise the CSS is broken.

Do I have to write code to setup plain CSS solving this or is there a dynamic Tailwind solution?

---

**Another approach:**

Based on [the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns) I tried to replace the line

```
container.classList.add(`grid-cols-${amountOfItemsPerRow}`);
```

with

```
container.classList.add(`grid-template-columns:repeat(${amountOfItemsPerRow},minmax(0,1fr))`);
```

to come up with a "native" approach but that didn't help.

Comment: Another solution would be to create a grid component and use that based on the amount of data columns returned from API, etc. You would end up with multiple 12 column grids.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot do that with plain TailwindCSS.

What @Ajay Raja suggests won't work because it only works with JIT (just-in-time); so previously to compiling the application you can use arbitrary values but once you've compiled and deployed your bundle that cannot be dynamic. **It only works during build-time; so if you're using a CDN you'll not make it**

What you can do is taking a look at the implementation of the class and set up some javascript listeners to dynamically set the style attribute:

From [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns) you can see the implementation of `.grid-columns-12`.

```css
.grid-columns-12 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
```

So from JS you can do something as follows:

```js
function setDynamicColumns(cols) {
  document
    .querySelector('#elementWithDynamicGrid')
    .style['grid-template-columns'] = `repeat(${cols}, minmax(0, 1fr))`
}
```

I am not a Vue expert, but you could set two-way databinding like you would on Angular or React.

What you were doing **here**

```js
container.classList.add(`grid-template-columns:repeat(${amountOfItemsPerRow},minmax(0,1fr))`)
```

Was not working because you were applying a `style` directive into the `class` attribute

---

Another approach to tackle this problem would be to generate the necessary amount of classes at build time so then you can use them safely at runtime:

If you take a look at the [docs here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns#using-custom-values)

You can add your own custom grid modifiers by modifying the `tailwind.config.js` file.

```js
module.exports = {  
  theme: {    
    extend: {      
      gridTemplateColumns: {        
      // Simple 16 column grid        
      '16': 'repeat(16, minmax(0, 1fr))',     
      }    
    }  
  }
}
```

So you can add a function that generates a reasonable number of columns there as follows:

```js
//tailwind.config.js
function generateGridColumns(lastValue) {
   let obj = {}
   for(let i = 13; i < lastValue; i++) {
     obj[`${i}`] = `repeat(${i}, minmax(0, 1fr))`
   }
   return obj
}


module.exports = {  
  theme: {    
    extend: {      
      gridTemplateColumns: {
         ...generateGridColumns(100) // This generates the columns from 12 until 100
      }    
    }  
  }
}
```

Please bear in mind that when purging your tailwindCSS builds you need to indicate to keep all `grid-columns-*` classes since the purger cannot guess that you're going to use them

Comment: interesting. My approach `container.classList.add(`grid-template-columns:repeat(${amountOfItemsPerRow},minmax(0,1fr))`)` didn't work. But yours `container.style['grid-template-columns'] = `repeat(${amountOfItemsPerRow},minmax(0,1fr))`` does ... reproduced it with https://jsfiddle.net/t94gfops/3/

Comment: Because we're dynamically setting the `style` attribute from the HTML. You were on the right path but setting a class that didn't exist

Comment: It's sad, that it does not work with TailwindCSS, because apparently it's integrated via postCSS. Since I am working on a custom calendar (existing ones do not fit my needs), I have a particular amount of grid column templates (2 to 8 columns), which I could add as custom templates and ensure I include those in the `safelist`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here for React.js & Next.js:

```
import { AllHTMLAttributes } from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";

// @interface IGrid extends all <div /> properties
interface IGrid extends AllHTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {}

export default function Grid({
  className = "",
  cols = 8,
  rows = 4,
  ...rest
}: IGrid) {
  const props = { className: classNames(className, "grid"), ...rest };
  const gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${cols}, 1fr)`;

  const gridItems = new Array(cols * rows)
    .fill("")
    .map((_, i) => <div key={`gridItem-${i}`}>{i}</div>);

  return (
    <div {...props} style={{ gridTemplateColumns }}>
      {gridItems}
    </div>
  );
}
```

✅ Tested in: `tailwindcss@3.3.3` without additional configuration.

⚠️ It isn't a best practice though:

> Microsoft Edge Tools: (no-inline-styles)

Answer (score -1):

Create Dynamic Class Name with Tailwindcss is easy.
Inside `[` and `]`, You can add Dynamic Class with TailwindCSS

```
const amountOfRows = 16;
const amountOfCellsPerRow = 16;

const container = document.getElementById("container");

for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < amountOfRows; rowIndex++) {
  for (let columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < amountOfCellsPerRow; columnIndex++) {
    const cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.innerText = rowIndex + "|" + columnIndex;
    container.appendChild(cell);
  }
}

container.classList.add(`grid-cols-[${amountOfCellsPerRow}]`)
```

For more details [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns)

Comment: but what needs to be done after wrapping it inside `[]`? I think the required css would be `grid-template-columns: repeat(amountOfCellsPerRow, minmax(0, 1fr));`

Comment: @medsmh Does my works fine?

Comment: sorry, no. I tested it with the CDN example from above