# NextJS: ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, next.js, loader

I am creating a npm package for myself.

I am using webpack, tailwind and storybook to create a UIKit.

It work fine on CRA. But when I tried to use in NextJS. I got an error `ReferenceError: document is not defined`

I tried to install `mini-css-extract-plugin` package to load css/scss file. But I got a new error `this.getoptions is not a function`

Anyone know how to resolve this issue? Please help me...

Thank for your times!!!

`webpack.base.js`

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.ejs$/,
        loader: 'ejs-loader'
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    globalObject: 'this',
    library: 'grace',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../lib'),
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  },
};
```

`webpack.production.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "grace",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Design System",
  "repository": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.3.8",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.3.8",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.3.8",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.3.8",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.31.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.31.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "ejs-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.2",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.39.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^8.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
    "ts-loader": "^8.3.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf lib",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "build": "yarn clean && NODE_ENV=development webpack --env development",
    "build-prod": "yarn clean && NODE_ENV=production webpack --env production",
    "check-types": "tsc --pretty --noEmit",
    "check-format": "prettier --check .",
    "check-lint": "eslint . --ext ts --ext tsx",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "test-all": "yarn check-format && yarn check-lint && yarn check-types",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "module": "lib/index.js",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "files": [
    "/lib"
  ],
  "resolutions": {
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "webpack": "4.44.2"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```js
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
import './button.scss';

export interface IButtonProps {
  type?: 'info' | 'success' | 'error' | 'warning' | 'default';
  backgroundColor?: string;
  size?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
  label: string;
  outline?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  onClick?: () => void;
}

const Button = ({
  type = 'default',
  size = 'medium',
  outline = false,
  backgroundColor,
  label,
  ...props
}: IButtonProps): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={[
        'grace-button',
        `grace-button--${size}`,
        `${
          outline
            ? `grace-button-outline grace-button-outline--${type}`
            : `grace-button--${type}`
        }`,
      ].join(' ')}
      style={{ backgroundColor }}
      {...props}
    >
      {label}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Comment: I think this is not related to CSS or webpack. It looks like it's looking for document and because NextJS it's SSR it may not be rendered yet.

Comment: You're calling document server side. The button code you provided won't throw the error. Is there a prop that is calling document? Show where you are calling document and the button.  You have a few bugs in your button - your tailwind styling will likely get purged (deleted) when you go into production - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68029107/15304814 - React buttons should extend React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> - you're losing standard HTML button props. You're overriding type with invalid HTML button type - you should rename your custom type prop to something like variant.

Comment: @ASG How can I fix that issue on NextJS?

Comment: @SeanW Thank you very much. I just refactor my code to avoid override button type. I have a little confuse about SSR mode. Can I fix the issue document is not defined on my button code. I want to my button code can work fine on both CRA and SSR.

Comment: If you want specific help, you have to show the code that is rendering the Button component. To fix this issue - in your parent component, check if the page is mounted in the browser before rendering the main content. See- https://www.joshwcomeau.com/snippets/react-hooks/use-has-mounted/