# Tailwind styles does not work in the production, Next.js and Vercel

Tags: next.js, deployment, tailwind-css, vercel

Why are certain CSS styles not being applied to my Next.js 14.1.3 website deployed on Vercel, despite being present in the code and working locally? I've tried using use client but to no avail. Here's the [deployed version](https://medical-portfolio-fawn.vercel.app/) and the [repo](https://github.com/A7medAbdien/medical-portfolio) for reference.

Deployed version
[image]

Local version
[image]

Deployed version console
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the custom color in tailwind not defined in NextJS production stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68029040/why-is-the-custom-color-in-tailwind-not-defined-in-nextjs-production-stage)

Comment: no, I tried it but the problem is not effecting only the color even such padding for buttons, positioning for card images. I will try to do it without next and see what will happen.